# How to update an character varying array using JDBC Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I am trying to update a character varying column in postgresql using JDBC Template.The approach i am using right now is like:

```
    String id=getId();
    String duser=getUser();

    //if count is 0
    if(count!=0){
    final String SQlString="update public.user set id=array_append(id,?)  where username= ?;
    jdbcTemplate.update(SQlString,new PreparedStatementSetter() {
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
    preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, duser);

    }
    });
    }


    //count not equal to zero 
    else
    {
    final String SQlString="update public.user set id = ?  where username=?;
    jdbcTemplate.update(SQlString,new PreparedStatementSetter() {
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
    preparedStatement.setString(1,"'{"+id+"}'");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, duser);

    }
    });
```

So basically if count is 0 then I have add the id and if not then I have append the array with existing elements. But this throws

> BADSQL Expression column id is character varying[] but expression is
>   character varying

But I know it is a string but how to set it to a postgresql Array Type (Not as a String Array).Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Updated question \Is it ok now?

Comment: What is the code trying to do? Is the business requirement to append some text to the user id under some circumstances? That sounds _really_ strange; and you should also expect referential integrity violations if the user id is used as a foreign key in some other table.

Comment: Not to mention that `id VARCHAR` sounds like textual primary keys. A good database design tutorial would probably be the right course of action here.

Comment: your deleted answer throws this **unable to find server array type for provided name varchar**

Comment: Argh, seems like the Postgres driver wants it as lowercase `varchar`.

Comment: To me, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain what you're trying to do (the logic you're trying to implement). It could be that you're looking for an `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`, but without more info, it's really hard to tell.

Comment: It is not an insert.it is an update only.The column will be intially empty.If there is a new id I have to update and set the new vale.If an existing entry is there for the column I have to append it.It is so easy

Comment: Okay, then just update the column value if it's empty; you don't need the `array_append` for anything. `VARCHAR` is semantically equal with Java `String`; you don't need to think about it as an array.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Sure he does. Because `id` is a `varchar[]`, not a `varchar`. It **is** an array. Of course he really shouldn't be using arrays, but it's probably not the worst part in his design.

Comment: Please post the table description.

Comment: @MickMnemonic `column id is character varying[]`.

Comment: Yes column id is character varying[] and username is character varying

Comment: @Ricky So did you try with the lowercase `varchar`? Or what are you waiting for?

Comment: Please post the table description to avoid the ambiguity; is it an array of VARCHARs or a VARCHAR? Because a [VARCHAR](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-character.html) is normally settable without using array functions.

Comment: Okay, the error message says it's an array of VARCHARs; @Ricky, the correct thing to do is just to re-create your table and use a VARCHAR column instead.

Comment: @MickMnemonic No it's not. He wants (apparently) to store several id values in a `VARCHAR[]`.

Comment: @Kayaman, well that just doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I'm not really sure what to say to that. I wouldn't design a database like that either, but maybe he'll learn a valuable lesson that array columns aren't very handy in the long run.

Comment: lower case varchar works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `PreparedStatement.setString()` for a `varchar[]` (i.e. array) column. You need to use `setArray()` with a 1 sized `java.sql.Array` containing the `String`.

```
Connection con = preparedStatement.getConnection();
Array a = con.createArrayOf("varchar", new Object[] {id});
preparedStatement.setArray(1, a);
```

Comment: I am not using connection.I am using connection pool HikariCP

Comment: You're not using connection? Do you know what the word "connection" means in "connection pool"?

Comment: I don't handle the connection If we use JDBC template it opens and closes the connection right.

Comment: You need to do more research. Get the connection from the `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea since I am requiring two connection for a single query.if I can convert the String to a SQL Array and then If I can update the prepared statement it is good i guess

Comment: It returns the same connection being used for the `PreparedStatement`, it doesn't fetch a second connection from the pool. You're making it really hard to help you, when you don't understand what you're doing and you don't understand what I'm saying.